# Using a FOR loop to rename files with a datestamp. Getting error "A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found."

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will rename every .txt file in the folder it's in to include a date stamp in the name. I've got it echoing out exactly as it should but when I try the same thing with rename or xcopy I get "A duplicate file name exists, or the file
cannot be found."

I'm new to batch and I can't quite figure out what's going on here. Maybe a small syntax issue?

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
goto :main

:main
    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a

    set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
    set MM=%dt:~4,2%
    set DD=%dt:~6,2%
    set HH=%dt:~8,2%
    set Min=%dt:~10,2%
    set Sec=%dt:~12,2%
    set stamp=!YYYY!-!MM!-!DD!___!HH!:!Min!:!Sec!

    echo !stamp!
    echo.

    FOR %%G IN (*.txt) DO (

        echo going to rename %%~nxG
        echo it will become  !stamp!___%%~nxG
        ren %%~nxG !stamp!___%%~nxG
        echo.
    )

    pause
goto :eof
```

Comment: You cannot use a colon `:` in a filename. That can generate the message "*A duplicate file name exists, or the file cannot be found.*".

Comment: I can understand a need to rename the files using their last written or created date, but cannot really see one for renaming each file with the date upon which the script was run. Perhaps you'd be kind enough to explain the idea.

Comment: I am with @Compo on this one, what is the reason for adding today's date to each text file? So even a file created 2 years ago will set it using todays date..

Comment: @Compo I work with a POS software that exports PDF reports at certain dates and times. After exporting a report, I can make it trigger a script file. That's where this script will come in to rename and move those files off to a dropbox folder. The script always runs on the date that the reports were exported and so I don't need to work with other dates.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your invalid filename characters, **<kbd>:</kbd>**, *which, as already mentioned in the comments, is the reason for your error message*, here's an example, replacing them with a **<kbd>.</kbd>**:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "stamp="
For /F "Tokens=1-6Delims=/: " %%A In ('""%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe" : : /NJH /L"'
)Do If Not Defined stamp Set "stamp=%%A-%%B-%%C___%%D.%%E.%%F"
If Not Defined stamp GoTo :EOF
For %%A In ("*.txt")Do If "%%~xA"==".txt" (Echo(&Echo going to rename %%~nxA
    Echo it will become %stamp%___%%~nxA&Ren "%%~nxA" "%stamp%___%%~nxA")
Pause
GoTo :EOF
```

Please note, you may need to consider some sort of filtering system to prevent any subsequent runs of the script from processing the same files, further increasing their names by another `24` characters.

Comment: Thanks! I knew I had to be missing something simple. I'm planning on moving the files as part of the loops so, I believe, that should prevent them from being renamed twice.